# Installing php 7.2 with extensions on MacOS with Extensions w/o Homebrew

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homebrew, laravel-valet

I wish to install php 7.2 on MacOS along with extensions (mentioned below) required to run Laravel -

```
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
```

I typically setup my development environment using Laravel Valet. However, as of now, I am unable to get sites running with https. Here are the steps I've done, and the error I'm getting -

1. Installed php using `brew install php@7.2`
2. Installed composer globally (without brew)
3. Installed Laravel Valet
4. Created new laravel site called `blog`
5. Accessed `http://blog.test` from browser and it loads fine
6. Ran `valet secure blog` to get self-signed SSL.
7. I now get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error on the site, upon accessing any page.

After much troubleshooting, I found out that the problem occurs as soon as I turn on ssl; using `valet secure` command.

I tried deleting everything, including configuration files and reinstalling everything. Nothing works.

My best guess now is that the error occurs because I haven't installed the required PHP extensions (mentioned above). However, I can't figure out how do I go about installing them. I tried `pecl install openssl` but it throws error.

Would really appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction. Thank you for your time in advance. Thank you!

PS: I'm using `nginx`.

Comment: PECL is for modules not part of PHP core. You probably want to do `brew install php-openssl` or something similar.